# Selenium WD Unable to locate webelement in a popup window on cheaptickets.in

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

On URL `"https://cheapticket.in/b2c/flights"`, after clicking on "signup" button a popup box appears, in which I want to enter the email and all other fields but following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
Element <input id="" class="fluid" name="login" type="text"> could not be
scrolled into view
```

```
package TestPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService;

public class CheapTickets {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.setProperty("driver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://cheapticket.in/b2c/flights");
        System.out.println("Loaded cheaptickets");

        //go to sign up
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='signup']")).click();
        System.out.println("Travelled to signup");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='fluid']")).sendKeys("abc@abc.com");
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: @ggorlen I have added the code done till now in the question.

Answer (score 0):

@SuperShazam looks like this locator finds 13 elements on in the DOM that could be the cause why Selenium throws an exception. Try to use a more specific locator for each element. If you are not able to create more specific locator try to iterate over elements and check if the desired one is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @baadnews, the xpath you used in your code to get input field of Email will match 13 elements in DOM. So your code will get the first match in DOM which is not visible on the page and you get the exception.

You can use more specific xpath like this

```
email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content']//input[@name='email']"))
mobile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content']//input[@name='mobile']"))
name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content']//input[@name='name']"))
```